# Qt 5 - как задать размер диалога относительно размера экрана?

Tags: c++, qt, экран, dpi

Приветствую.
Только что обнаружил, что всё делаю неправильно... У меня все размеры диалогов в пикселях, а нужно в процентах от размера экрана. Облазил весь Qt Designer, не нашёл таких настроек. Как это сделать? У меня версия Qt 5.5.1.

Comment: Таких настроек там нет. В процентах от размера экрана размеры задать нельзя. Но можно определить размер экрана и при отображении диалога сменить его размеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем в конструктор виджета.

```
#define PERCENT_OF_SCREEN (25 / 100)
QRect r = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
this->resize(r.width() * PERCENT_OF_SCREEN, r.height() * PERCENT_OF_SCREEN);
```

тут `(25 / 100)` первое число это размер виджета в процентах от размера экрана.

Comment: В вопросе про дизайнер речь идет, судя по всему.

Comment: А вы в курсе, что screenGeometry получает всё суммарное разрешение, включая разрешения с других экранов.

Comment: Нужно использовать так: `QRect *screenRect = QApplication::screens().at(0)->geometry();`, только #include <QScreen> сделай.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко В документации такого нет 
"Returns the geometry of the screen with index screen. The default screen is used if screen is -1."

Comment: Это я написал не слишком понятно. Речь действительно о размере шрифтов, о дизайнере и о неправильности размеров в пикселях. Layout не поможет, он только внутри формы. Ответ можно принять, мне не только дизайнер нужен. Замечания учту. Всем благодарность. Всё равно у меня один экран, до версии Qt 5.6 приложение по умолчанию Application DPI-Aware, масштаб определяется на всё приложение, и ещё там грабли - непонятно, откуда брать коэффициент масштаба, но я разбираюсь.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, указывать какие-то конкретные и даже относительные размеры виджетам не слишком правильно. В Qt имеется абсолютно всё для того, чтобы потом не было мучительно больно за криво подобранные координаты или процентные коэффициенты, буде программа окажется запущена на экране с альтернативными настройками, типа увеличенных шрифтов и тому подобного. Лучше позволить менеджерам размещения (`QLayout`) самим подстраивать размеры диалогов, чтобы интерфейс пользователя выглядел аккуратно при любом раскладе.